# Foto tirada pela minha app não aparece na Galeria

Tags: android

Ao gerar a foto através do meu app ele cria corretamente a pasta e salva as fotos tiradas lá, mas quando vou na galeria do Celular é como se as fotos não existissem, a galeria padrão do Android não reconhece os arquivos.

Alguém saberia me dizer se tem alguma permissão que preciso dar para que as fotos possam ser visualizadas na galeria? Ou até mesmo se isso seria uma configuração do Android.

Estou Utilizando a 4.0 do Android

```java
private void addImage() {    
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);    
     intent.setData(uri);           
     this.sendBroadcast(intent);    
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a *Galeria* só é atualizada, pelo SO do Android, de tempos a tempos.

Para que a *Galeria* seja actualizada imediatamente você necessita de chamar o método `scanFile` da classe `MediaScannerConnection`.

Defina os seguintes métodos no seu programa:

```
void doScanFile(String fileName) {
        String[] filesToScan = {fileName};

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, filesToScan, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String filePath, Uri uri) {
                        mediaFileScanComplete(filePath, uri);
                    }
                });
}

void mediaFileScanComplete(String mediaFilePath, Uri mediaFileUri) {

   //Guarde esta informação se você necessitar dela.
    _lastMediaFilePath = mediaFilePath;
    _lastMediaFileUri = mediaFileUri;
}
```

Chame o método `doScanFile(fileName)` após ter salvo a foto.

Em alternativa pode lançar um Broadcast para indicar que houve uma alteração no arquivo de mídia:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName))));
```

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, muito obrigado