# Ao deletar foto da galeria o arquivo ainda existe na galeria sem imagem

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando deletar uma foto da galeria via código pelo android studio. Após a execução do código o arquivo da foto ainda permanece lá sem a imagem contendo uma exclamação como imagem. O nome, tamanho e detalhes ainda continuam, vejam o código::

```
File imagem = new File(v_CaminhoFoto + "/" + v_nome_foto);
imagem.delete();
```

Me parece que ele está limpando apenas o bitmap da foto e preservando o arquivo.

Android manifest já esta:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: Isso acontece porque a Galeria só é actualizada, pelo SO do Android, de tempos a tempos. Veja se esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/24996/2541) resolve o problema.

Comment: Veja também se [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716773/2570426) resolve o problema.

Comment: Verdade, obrigado pela ajuda. Este simples código atualiza a galeria:  // atualiza galeria para este arquivo excluido
                                                                                  
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(v_CaminhoFoto + "/" + v_nome_foto))));