# Salvar na galeria imagem tirada pela câmera e pegar caminho dessa imagem. - Android

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação android que usa a câmera para tirar fotos e mostrar em um `ImageView`, só que a foto tirada não é salva na galeria. Gostaria de saber como salvar a imagem na galeria e pegar o caminho dessa imagem que foi salva, pois preciso dela para usar em outra função. Abaixo segue o código do que fiz até o momento:

```
public class Capturar extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final int CAMERA = 1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private String caminhoDaImagem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capturar);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
    }

    public void usarCamera(View view) {

        Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(it, CAMERA);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

OBS: O que eu quero pegar é a imagem REAL tirada pela câmera. Do modo que está no código que eu postei, o que está sendo mostrado no `ImageView` é apenas um thumbnail temporário gerado e não a foto real.

Comment: Relacionado: [Dúvidas em relação ao uso da câmera, via Intent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147398/2541)

Comment: @ramaral obrigado por responder, mas essa solução não resolve o meu problema. O que eu quero é que a foto tirada pela câmera vá direto pra galeria e depois de salva na galeria eu ter uma forma de pegar o endereço dela. Da forma como foi feito nessa solução que você mencionou, é necessário criar uma pasta no cartão SD do smartphone onde a aplicação irá rodar, o que não pode acontecer na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo. Ainda assim, muito obrigado pela atenção e por responder!

Comment: As fotos não são gravadas na Galeria. A Galeria é um banco de dados onde é guardado, entre outras coisas, o *path* para as fotos existentes no dispositivo. A sua aplicação deve gravá-la numa determinada localização e depois informar a Galeria disso. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/24996/2541) para saber como.

Comment: Entendi @ramaral, de fato acabei me equivocando nesse assunto pois ainda sou leigo nele. Consegui entender que a galeria é apenas um banco de dados que armazena os caminhos onde as imagens estão. O que eu queria era que a minha aplicação salvasse as fotos tiradas em uma das pastas padrões que estão no dispositivo, assim como o app nativo da câmera faz.
O usuário "MonitorLPI" conseguiu me ajudar nesta questão, mas agradeço muito a você por me esclarecer esse assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que desse jeito vai funcionar, qualquer dúvida, só postar.

```
public class Capturar extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final int CAMERA = 1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private String caminhoDaImagem;
    private Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capturar);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
    }

    public void usarCamera(View view) {

        File diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imagem = new File(diretorio.getPath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        uri  = Uri.fromFile(imagem);

        Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intentCamera, CAMERA);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if(requestCode == CAMERA){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

               Intent novaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
               sendBroadcast(novaIntent);

               caminhoDaImagem = uri.getPath();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou amigo, muito obrigado por responder!